# Che terminologia uso per esprimere l'idea che due verbi esprimono la stessa azione ma invertono il ruolo di soggetto e "destinatario"?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage

(Per "destinatario" intendo complemento oggetto, di termine, o qualsiasi altro venga usato per codificare il ricevitore dell'azione; immagino ci sia un termine ad-hoc anche per questo, no?)

Ad esempio, *prestare* e *prendere in prestito*: *io **presto** a te* è lo stesso che *tu **prendi in prestito** da me* (al netto della presenza o assenza del consenso delle parti, ahah), o *tu **piaci** a me* è analogo a *io **amo** te* (al netto dell'intensità del sentimento, ma ai fini delle mia domanda diciamo che siano uguali)¹.

Da ingegnere programmatore direi che i due verbi di ciascuna coppia accettano gli stessi argomenti, ma invertiti, e producono lo stesso effetto.

Come lo dico in italiano in "tecnichese"?

---

(¹) Nel 1600, leggo da un libro di linguistica, l'inglese *like* aveva soggetto e oggetto invertiti rispetto ad oggi, quindi collocato nel 1600, l'esempio che ho fatto regge anche in inglese, *I **like** you* era lo stesso che *you **love** me*.

Comment: “_I like you_ è lo stesso che _you love me_”: non direi proprio... Forse stai pensando all'italiano, dove “tu mi piaci” è analogo a “io ti amo” (a parte appunto l'intensità)?

Comment: Eh, scusa, ho fatto confusione e ho dimenticato una info fondamentale, che poi è il motivo da cui nasce la mia domanda, e cioè che nel 1600 il significato era quello che dici.

Comment: Giusto, grazie! Non lo avevo ben presente, ma in effetti qualche esempio si trova anche in Shakespeare, come “Like it your Grace, The State takes notice” (Piaccia a vostra Grazia...) nell'_Enrico VIII_.